# Batch Remove all files without extensions from list

Tags: list, batch-file, directory, text-files

I am making a simple program to list all the files in a certain folder and I want to remove all files (from the text file or wherever is more efficient) that don't have extensions.

This is my current code:

```
dir /s/b *.* > E:/Project.sav 
for /f "Delims=" %%A in (E:/Project.sav) do (
 echo %%A
)
```

and I get a mix of files like this:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop\TEst\05f429069e65dwqewqeqweqeq0a3f294cc3128ab
C:\Users\User\Desktop\TEst\063bf0fui3ucinyh3ruincuiwhwu3gssssybwyrbweib
C:\Users\User\Desktop\TEst\hs_err_pid3080.log
C:\Users\User\Desktop\TEst\hs_err_pid5220.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need the intermediate file, then all you need is the DIR command:

```
dir /s /b *.
```

Note that the above will include directory names as well as file names, as does your original code. If you only want files, then add the `/A-D` option:

```
dir /s /b /a-d *.
```

If you need the complete listing in E:/Project.sav, then you can use FINDSTR with a regular expression to filter out the entries that contain an extension:

```
findstr /vr "\.[^\\]*$" "E:/Project.sav"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if "%%~xA" neq ""  echo %%A
```

should do what you want.

If "the extension of the filename in %%A" is not equal to "" echo....